# Adding a tabhost in viewflipper

Tags: android

I am new to this platform and already starting to love it. I am work 
on a UI for a project which uses the tabhost to display two separate 
activities using a TabActivity class. This works ok. 
Now i would like to add a viewflipper to the equation. I am trying to 
add the tabhost widget to the viewflipper using the addView() method. 
Eg:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity { 
        @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
                TabHost host = getTabHost(); 
                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("First").setContent( 
                                new Intent(this, First.class))); 
                host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Second") 
                                .setContent(new Intent(this, Second.class))); 
               Button btn1 = new Button(this); 
               btn1.setText("Second Screen"); 
               flipper = new ViewFlipper(this); 
               flipper.addView(host); 
               flipper.addView(btn1); 
               setContentView(flipper); 
        } 
}
```

The main motive is to an application with two activities all tabbed. 
The viewflipper will then flip between these two activities. I am 
thinking an alternative will be to use xml layout to hold the tabhost 
and just include it in the view. 
I am avoiding it for now because that would mean me writing the codes 
for the two classes again. 
To round all this up, is there a way to include a tabhost in a 
viewflipper.

Thanks,

New Guy

Answer (score 1):

You should write it inside the XML instead of hard-coded. it's easier and looks better.

Here i've created a tabhost, which is holding a ViewFlipper of 2 listviews, and another listview in other tab

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/title_text"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
     />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="15dp"
        >

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listfav" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>

        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewflipper" 
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        > 
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listmain" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listsub" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>
        </ViewFlipper>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how you do it..